# Conversion Exception for BasicDataSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, datasource, applicationcontext

In trying to create a demo Spring-MVC application, I'm running into an issue on startup:

ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` to required type `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` for property `dataSource`; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of 
type [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] to required type [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for property `dataSource`: no matching 
editors or conversion strategy found

My question is, why does Tomcat think it needs to convert the BasicDataSource when it's defined in the `applicationContext.xml` file as

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
```

I can't see where it's getting that from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the Captain-Kirk approach to solving this problem: I changed the parameters of the situation. Instead of trying to figure out why my new demo application, I copied an existing app then slowly changed and deleted things so that I got to my demo application. A more laborious approach, for sure, but I achieved my results ultimately...